# Place a decimal point into a number

Tags: r

I have a variable of a df which contains numbers, but I need to transform it into decimals

An example:

```
[1]  NA  NA  NA 595 595   5
```

so I need to create a new variable or transform it to get the following form

```
[1]  NA NA NA 5.95 5.95 5.0
```

but I haven't find a way to do this, I'll appreciate any help

I have looking ways, but the only thing I find is a stata command

```
destring v1, g(new_var) dpcomma
     drop v1
```

and I don't understand it

result from str

```
num [1:308535] NA NA NA 595 595 5 625 645 59 54 ...
```

an extract from dput

```
515, 555, 478, 665, 635, 555, 608, 578, 633, 62, 59, 608, 498, 
603, 54, 638, 565, 625, NA, 545, 613, 573, 543, 653, 523, 568, 
508, 635, 625, 598, 62, 565, 545, 655, 628, 52, 588, 598, 55, 
598, 55, 578, 515, 64, 54, 54, 625, 565, 608, 588, 618, 535, 
603, 663, 558, 638, 59, 518, 54, 613, 495, 535, 51, 543, 613, 
583, 58, 593, 498, 568, 538, 525, 653, 555, 588, 56, 505, 54, 
618, 56, 623, 508, 595, 6, 585, 518, 545, 525, 603, 588, 575, 
568, 568, 588, 595, 593, 565, 535, 563, 643, 57, 645, 608, 608, 
555, 57, 54, 555, 61, 528, 623, 653, 618, 528, 563, 63, 538, 
52, 563, 51, 538, 525, 558, 568, NA, 523, 623, NA, 603, 555, 
48, 633, 575, 583, 54, 578, 56, 65, 525, 5, 595, 663, 618, 59, 
603, 525, 54, 555, 625, 528, 538, 67, 64, 528, 623, 615, 565, 
548, 65, 508, 653, 63, 58, 553, 553, 548, 575, 553, 538, 583, 
565, 613, 608, 68, 55, 605, 675, 585, 533, 565, 515, 525, 568,
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We need some more information, please: (1) can you include the results of `str(df$var)` or `dput(df$var)` in your question, so we can see exactly what you have?  (2) Can you clarify that all variables in the string should have exactly one value to the left of the decimal place after tranformation? (3) Your title talks about commas, but I don't see any commas in your question.  Do you mean "decimal separator" (which is typically `.` but can be `,` in some European locales) ?

Comment: I dont know if I understand correctly the problem but it seems like you could just take the original variable and divide it by 100. In R `df$newVar <- df$originalVar / 100`

Comment: @MikeKatz45 i thought in that, but i need to pass all the numbers in to a rate, for example, if i have a 5 i need it as a 5.0, if i have a 567 i need it as a 5.67, so if i divide  the variable by 100 y would have  a 0.05 and not a 5.0

Comment: Your logic is under-described, but consider the `ifelse` function: `x / ifelse(x < 100, 1, 100)` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @BenBolker  i put the results in the original post

Comment: so you basically want to always have a single digit in the integer part and the rest to be in the decimals?

Comment: (1) Please don't give an "extract from dput". It's better to give `dput` from the extract of data. The difference is that the (unedited) output of `dput` is immediately usable to us, whereas your current extract still requires some work to be able to use, and we still have no context in the rest of your object structure. (2) Please spend a few moments to describe to use what you mean by *"pass all the numbers in to a rate"*, does that mean that anything under 100 is already good, and over 100 needs to be scaled? *We don't know.*

Comment: @MikeKatz45 exactly

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (this assumes your input is never 0, if this can happen you need to set `Inf` values to 0 at the end of the process):

```
# first define a function that will to the job
toRate <- function(x) {      

  # get number of digits minus one
  ndigits <- ceiling(log10(abs(x))) - 1 # or use floor and skip the -1
  # divide by a power of 10 according to number of digits
  y <- x / (10^ndigits)


  return(y)
}

original <- c(515, 555, 478, 665, 635, 555, 608, 578, 633, 62, 59, 608, 498, 
603, 54, 638, 565, 625, NA, 545, 613, 573, 543, 653, 523, 568, 
508, 635, 625, 598, 62, 565, 545, 655, 628, 52, 588, 598, 55, 
598, 55, 578, 515, 64, 54, 54, 625, 565, 608, 588, 618, 535, 
603, 663, 558, 638, 59, 518, 54, 613, 495, 535, 51, 543, 613, 
583, 58, 593, 498, 568, 538, 525, 653, 555, 588, 56, 505, 54, 
618, 56, 623, 508, 595, 6, 585, 518, 545, 525, 603, 588, 575, 
568, 568, 588, 595, 593, 565, 535, 563, 643, 57, 645, 608, 608, 
555, 57, 54, 555, 61, 528, 623, 653, 618, 528, 563, 63, 538, 
52, 563, 51, 538, 525, 558, 568, NA, 523, 623, NA, 603, 555, 
48, 633, 575, 583, 54, 578, 56, 65, 525, 5, 595, 663, 618, 59, 
603, 525, 54, 555, 625, 528, 538, 67, 64, 528, 623, 615, 565, 
548, 65, 508, 653, 63, 58, 553, 553, 548, 575, 553, 538, 583, 
565, 613, 608, 68, 55, 605, 675, 585, 533, 565, 515, 525, 568)
df <- cbind.data.frame(original = original)
df$new <- toRate(df$original)
```

Output:

```
df$new
[1] 5.15 5.55 4.78 6.65 6.35 5.55
  [7] 6.08 5.78 6.33 6.20 5.90 6.08
 [13] 4.98 6.03 5.40 6.38 5.65 6.25
 [19]   NA 5.45 6.13 5.73 5.43 6.53
 [25] 5.23 5.68 5.08 6.35 6.25 5.98
 [31] 6.20 5.65 5.45 6.55 6.28 5.20
 [37] 5.88 5.98 5.50 5.98 5.50 5.78
 [43] 5.15 6.40 5.40 5.40 6.25 5.65
 [49] 6.08 5.88 6.18 5.35 6.03 6.63
 [55] 5.58 6.38 5.90 5.18 5.40 6.13
 [61] 4.95 5.35 5.10 5.43 6.13 5.83
 [67] 5.80 5.93 4.98 5.68 5.38 5.25
 [73] 6.53 5.55 5.88 5.60 5.05 5.40
 [79] 6.18 5.60 6.23 5.08 5.95 6.00
 [85] 5.85 5.18 5.45 5.25 6.03 5.88
 [91] 5.75 5.68 5.68 5.88 5.95 5.93
 [97] 5.65 5.35 5.63 6.43 5.70 6.45
[103] 6.08 6.08 5.55 5.70 5.40 5.55
[109] 6.10 5.28 6.23 6.53 6.18 5.28
[115] 5.63 6.30 5.38 5.20 5.63 5.10
[121] 5.38 5.25 5.58 5.68   NA 5.23
[127] 6.23   NA 6.03 5.55 4.80 6.33
[133] 5.75 5.83 5.40 5.78 5.60 6.50
[139] 5.25 5.00 5.95 6.63 6.18 5.90
[145] 6.03 5.25 5.40 5.55 6.25 5.28
[151] 5.38 6.70 6.40 5.28 6.23 6.15
[157] 5.65 5.48 6.50 5.08 6.53 6.30
[163] 5.80 5.53 5.53 5.48 5.75 5.53
[169] 5.38 5.83 5.65 6.13 6.08 6.80
[175] 5.50 6.05 6.75 5.85 5.33 5.65
[181] 5.15 5.25 5.68
```

Comment: thank u very much

Comment: please consider improving your question with the comments from the people who took the time to review it

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to insert a `.` after the first character with `stringr::str_sub` then convert back to `numeric`.

```r
x <- c(515, 555, 478, 665, 635, 555, 608, 578, 633, 62, 59)

stringr::str_sub(x, 2, 1) <- "."

as.numeric(x)

#----

[1] 5.15 5.55 4.78 6.65 6.35 5.55 6.08 5.78 6.33 6.20 5.90
```

---

Or with base function `sub`

```r
as.numeric(sub("^(.{1})", "\\1\\.", x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
x/10^(nchar(x) - 1)

 [1] 5.15 5.55 4.78 6.65 6.35 5.55 6.08 5.78 6.33 6.20 5.90
```